# Presto JDBC Data Source Error in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, jdbc, presto

Anyone know how to add a Presto data source to IntelliJ? The Database Tool Window has lots of Data Source type options, but doesn't have one for a Presto Data Source.

I checked the IntelliJ site and there seems to be no support as of yet. Wondering if there's a way to add it anyway so I can query from IntelliJ using Presto.

When I try adding the Presto driver manually using "Add Datasource", I get the following when I try to "Test Connection":

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -5
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1931)
    at com.facebook.presto.jdbc.PrestoDriverUri.parseDriverUrl(PrestoDriverUri.java:195)
    at com.facebook.presto.jdbc.PrestoDriverUri.<init>(PrestoDriverUri.java:79)
    at com.facebook.presto.jdbc.PrestoDriver.getPropertyInfo(PrestoDriver.java:106)
    at com.intellij.database.remote.jdbc.impl.RemoteDriverImpl.getPropertyInfo(RemoteDriverImpl.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:346)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:276)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:253)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:162)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:227)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:179)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy196.getPropertyInfo(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil.invokeRemote(RemoteUtil.java:175)
    at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil.access$300(RemoteUtil.java:36)
    at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil$RemoteInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteUtil.java:280)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy197.getPropertyInfo(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.database.view.ui.DatabaseDriverPropertiesPanel.lambda$null$0(DatabaseDriverPropertiesPanel.java:223)
    at com.intellij.database.dataSource.DatabaseConnectionManager.useDriver(DatabaseConnectionManager.java:145)
    at com.intellij.database.view.ui.DatabaseDriverPropertiesPanel.lambda$refreshAdvancedProperties$2(DatabaseDriverPropertiesPanel.java:222)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:330)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) (no stack trace)
```

Comment: Works now. The fix was to revert to an old driver: presto-jdbc-0.146.jar. That's working for me, whereas presto-jdbc-0.180.1.jar throws the above error.

Answer (score 1):

With IntelliJ IDEA you can connect to any database which provides corresponding jdbc driver. As there is no out-of-the-box Presto support in IDE you can create a **custom data source** for it using [Presto jdbc driver](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/installation/jdbc.html). You can check [this tutorial](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/connecting-to-a-database.html#vertica_as_unsupported_dbms) as an example of such data source creation.

Comment: Thanks, Andrey. I actually tried this, but got an error when I try to Test Connection (see above).

Comment: What url are you specifying? Based on the exception (which is thrown by the jdbc driver [here](https://github.com/prestodb/presto/blob/ded9003af151e5ef5ebc3f2c87930535e2afcbc6/presto-jdbc/src/main/java/com/facebook/presto/jdbc/PrestoDriverUri.java#L195)) it looks like it has problems parsing the connection url. Please make sure the url syntax is correct.

Comment: Good to know. Strange thing is I haven't changed the URL (jdbc:presto://localhost:8083/page). But I reverted the driver back to 0.146 (see above) and it now works.

Comment: Interestingly, it says here that "We can currently use the jdbc driver..." for Presto: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-4719. However, it does not specify the driver it is referring to, and that statement does not seem to be true for presto-jdbc-0.180.1.jar.

Comment: It makes sense to report the exception issue to [presto jdbc driver tracker](https://github.com/prestodb/presto/issues)

Comment: Thanks. Will do. Haven't gotten around to registering on the site so as to do so yet.